# Error reading protobuf spec. validator error:

Tags: swift, coreml

I am trying to get the URL of a compiled Model.

```
do {
   let compiledModelURL: URL = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelAddress)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

It was working with one set of data, but when I passed in new data, I'm getting the following error which I don't understand at all.

```
Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: unable to open file for read
```

Comment: It probably means the mlmodel file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when my `modelAddress` variable omitted the `.mlmodel` file ending.

```
"myFileName" vs "myFileName.mlmodel"
```

Comment: I had the full name with extension, but still getting it

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the sandbox for the application and it did work or changing FileAccess permissions and keeping mlmodel inside one of that folder.

How to delete a sandbox?

[image]